# Intercept and delete keyboard events

Tags: input

I want to attach a Bluetooth keyboard to a headless Raspberry Pi, and somehow intercept the key presses (including Ctrl+Shift+X combinations), and then remove them from the system so that they don't interact with the system anymore.

I never attach a keyboard to my Raspberry Pies and only interact with them via SSH, and I would like to continue to do it that way. Only if a hardware keyboard is attached, I want to redirect those keypresses (and releases) of that hardware into a Python script in order to use the keyboard for home automation stuff, as a control surface.

The devices also have no X-servers installed and it should remain that way.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboards should end up being recognised as standard HID (human interface) devices and appear as a device under `/dev/input/`. You can read events from the device with `evtest`, or from Python through a library [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There may be other similar libraries. I don't know of a package for raspian, but there was certainly an rpm for Fedora by the name of `python-evdev`.

`evtest` with no parameters will list the devices and ask you to choose one to monitor for events. You will probably need to use something like `inotifywait` to look for new devices appearing in `/dev/input/`. The Python library similarly can list and monitor a device, but I don't think it can detect new ones without polling. If you ask to `grab` a device, no one else will get the events.

Typical `evtest` output when you press `enter`:

```
Event: time 1509452892.590022, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70028
Event: time 1509452892.590022, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1509452892.590022, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1509452894.005980, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70028
Event: time 1509452894.005980, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 1
Event: time 1509452894.005980, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```